# local notificação com scheduler no ionic 4 não funciona no sdk 28+ quando usa o trigger

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

Funciona

```
 this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      summary: "Amanhã  3444" ,
      text: 'teste local notification ',
      smallIcon: "res://icone_in",

      title: "aaaa 3",

      led: 'FF0000',
      sound: null
   });
```

não funciona

```
 this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      summary: "Amanhã  3444" ,
      text: 'teste local notification ',
      smallIcon: "res://icone_in",

      title: "aaaa 3",
      trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10000)},
      led: 'FF0000',
      sound: null
   });
```

estou usando

```
 import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/';
```

Obrigado

Comment: Você sabe quando tempo é `new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10000)`? Pela conta, seriam 10 segundos no futuro, você esperou os 10 segundos com o app aberto?

Comment: sim   deixei  bem mais   fiz testes quando eu adiciono tempo não triga

Answer (score 0):

Você tentou importar da seguinte forma?

```
import {LocalNotifications} from "@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx";
```

No momento estou utilizando a versão local-notifications@5.27.0

Também é necessário verificar se o usuário deu permissão

```
this.localNotifications.hasPermission().then(permission => {
    console.log(`hasPermission: ${permission}`);
    if (permission) {
        this.localNotifications.schedule({
            id: 1,
            text: notification.title,
            data: notification
        });
    } else {
        this.localNotifications.requestPermission().then(value => {
            console.log(`requestPermission: ${value}`);
            if (value) {
                this.localNotifications.schedule({
                    id: 1,
                    text: notification.title,
                    data: notification
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Sem permissão para notificações locais");
            }
        });
    }
});
```